# onfocus/onblur in laravel form

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

There is html form code, writing that into laravel which converts this.value=='' into this.value==#039; how to write this.value=='' in laravel ?

```
<input class="form-control select-design" required value="Years of Work Experience" name="experience" type="text" required onblur="if(this.value==''){ this.value='Years of Work Experience'; this.style.color='#BBB';}" onfocus="if(this.value=='Years of Work Experience'){ this.value=''; this.style.color='#000';}" style="color:#BBB;">
```

Writing it into laravel(php)

```
{!! Form::text('experience', null, ['class' => 'form-control select-design','value' => 'Years of Work Experience','name'=>"experience",'type'=>"text",'onblur'=>"if(this.value==''){ this.value='Years of Work Experience'; this.style.color='#BBB';}",'onfocus' => "if(this.value=='Years of Work Experience'){ this.value=''; this.style.color='#000';}",'style'=>"color:#BBB;"]) !!}
```

It shows actual code like this

```
<input class="form-control select-design" name="experience" type="text" onblur="if(this.value==&#039;&#039;){ this.value=&#039;Years of Work Experience&#039;; this.style.color=&#039;#BBB&#039;;}" onfocus="if(this.value==&#039;Years of Work Experience&#039;){ this.value=&#039;&#039;; this.style.color=&#039;#000&#039;;}" style="color:#BBB;">
```

Is there any issue with syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in `Form::text()` since it's using `htmlspecialchars()` function and you can't change that. What you can do is [create custom macro](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#custom-macros). But still I believe it's terrible idea to hardcode JS functions into Laravel Collective forms.

Best thing you can do is to move all JS logic to JS file and do something like this:

```
$("#element").blur(....);
```

Or you could use simple HTML forms. But moving all JS logic out from HTML is the best choice.

Comment: You mean writing the javascript code in a function and then calling that onclick and onblur ? i know javascript a little so

Comment: Yes, you can do that and also you can completely remove JS from the HTML and use example from my answer to bind event to some functionality. You may want to read some tutorial or [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to get the idea.